# Computing expectation of $\frac{x_1^2 x_2^2}{\|x\|^4}$ for Gaussian $x$

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I want to figure out the formula for the following two expectations for $x$ distributed as standard normal in $d$ dimensions:

$$\begin{align}
u_d&=E\left[\frac{x_1^4}{\|x\|^4}\right]\\
v_d&=E\left[\frac{x_1^2 x_2^2}{\|x\|^4}\right]
\end{align}
$$

`NIntegrate` followed by `Rationalize` suggests there's a simple formula but gets slow for $d>3$, any tips?

```
d = 3;
Clear[x];
xvec = Array[x, d];
norm4 = Total[xvec*xvec]^2;
pdf = PDF[MultinormalDistribution[IdentityMatrix[d]], xvec];
bounds = {#, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]} & /@ xvec;
NIntegrate @@ Join[{pdf*x[1]^4/norm4}, bounds]
NIntegrate @@ Join[{pdf*x[1]^2 x[2]^2/norm4}, bounds]
```

Motivation: repeatedly project $w$ onto random plane passing through origin. Expected norm of $w$ after $d$ projections is determined by $u_d,v_d$.

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/richtarik-stepsizes-simulation.nb)

Comment: Normalizing, you can think of your random points as uniformly distributed on the surface of a hypersphere. They can be computed as trigonometric integrals.

Comment: You only need to work on one of $u_d$ and $v_d$ as $d u_d+\frac{d(d-1)}{2} v_d=1$ as $1=E[1]=
E\left[\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^2)^2}{(\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^2])^2}\right]
=E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^4+2\sum_{i=2}^d\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_i^2 x_j^2}{||x||^2}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^d E\left[\frac{x_i^4}{||x||^2}\right] +
2\sum_{i=2}^d \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} E\left[\frac{x_i^2 x_j^2}{||x||^2}\right]=
d u_d+\frac{d(d-1)}{2} v_d$.

Comment: I think $u_d=3/(d(d+2))$ and that this question probably belongs on math.SE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only one of $u_d$ and $v_d$ needs to be efficiently calculated as $d u_d+\frac{d(d-1)}{2} v_d=1$:

$$1=E[1]=
E\left[\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^4)^2}{(\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^2])^2}\right]
=E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^4+2\sum_{i=2}^d\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_i^2 x_j^2}{||x||^2}\right]$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^d E\left[\frac{x_i^4}{||x||^2}\right] +
2\sum_{i=2}^d \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} E\left[\frac{x_i^2 x_j^2}{||x||^2}\right]=
d u_d+\frac{d(d-1)}{2} v_d
$$

$z_1=x_1^2$ has a chisquare distribution with 1 degree of freedom.  $z_2=x_2^2+\cdots+x_d^2$ has a chisquare distribution with $d-1$ degrees of freedom and $z_1$ and $z_2$ are independent. We have

$$u_d=E\left[\frac{z_1^2}{(z_1+z_2)^2}\right]$$:

```
Integrate[(z1^2/(z1 + z2)^2) E^(-z1/2)/(Sqrt[2 π] Sqrt[z1])*
  (2^((1 - d)/2) E^(-z2/2) z2^(-1 + 1/2 (-1 + d)))/Gamma[1/2 (-1 + d)],
  {z1, 0, ∞}, {z2, 0, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> d ∈ Integers && d >= 2]

(* 3/(d (2 + d)) *)
```

Therefore $v_d$ is found in the following manner:

```
(Solve[1 == d ud + vd d (d - 1)/2, vd] /. ud -> 3/(d (2 + d)))[[1]] // FullSimplify
(* {vd -> 2/(2 d + d^2)} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

The integral of $\sin^n x$ over $[0,\pi]$ is given by
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\; \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}$$
The integral of an even power of $\cos x$ will be the same.
We actually will integrate the power of $\cos x$ over $[0,2\pi]$,
so the integral will be twice that.
The integral for
$$u_{d,2k}=E\left[\frac{x_d^{2k}}{\|x\|^4}\right]$$
can be expressed in spherical coordinates as
$$\int _0^{\infty }\int _0^{\pi }\cdots\int
   _0^{\pi }\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\frac{e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}} r^{d + 2 k - 5} \sin
   ^{2 k + d - 2}\left(\phi _1\right) \cdots \sin ^{2 k + 1}\left(\phi _{d-2}\right) \cos
   ^{2k}\left(\phi _{d-1}\right)}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}d\phi _ {d-1} d\phi _ {d-2}\cdots d\phi _1dr
$$
which can be separated into a product of $d$ independent integrals.
So $u_{d,2k}$ may be expressed as twice the product of
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\; \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)} \quad\text{for}\ n=2k,\dots, 2 k + d - 2$$
and
$$
\pi ^{-d/2} 2^{k-3} \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}+k-2\right)
$$
The product of the gamma factors is telescoping and the whole may be simplified to the following:

```
Clear[d, k];
Assuming[
 d \[Element] Integers && d >= 1 && k \[Element] Integers && k > 1,
 2 ((Sqrt[\[Pi]])^(d - 1) Gamma[(1 + 2 k)/2])/
   Gamma[1 + (2 k + d - 2)/2] Integrate[
    E^(-(r^2/2)) r^(d + 2 k - 5)/(2 Pi)^(d/2), {r, 0, Infinity}] // 
  FullSimplify
 ]
(*
  (2^k Gamma[1/2 + k])/((-4 + d + 2 k) (-2 + d + 2 k) Sqrt[π])
*)
```

To get the result in the OP, substitute `k -> 2`.

```
(2^k Gamma[1/2 + k])/((-4 + d + 2 k) (-2 + d + 2 k) Sqrt[π]) /. 
 k -> 2
(*
  3/(d (2 + d))
*)
```